# BeanException is not correctly resolved in Idea IDE

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

the code:

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Hello {
    private String s;

    public Hello(String str){
        s = str;
    }

    public void sayHi(){
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    public static void main(String []args){
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ac = null;//
        try {
            ac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"config.xml"});
            Hello h = (Hello) ac.getBean("hello");//
            h.sayHi();
        } catch (BeansException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }
    }
}
```

The problem that IntelliJ Idea marks red:
[image]

It is strange because BeansException inhertis from Throwable:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.2/api/org/springframework/beans/BeansException.html
What the reason and how to fix?

Comment: What happens if you build your project?

Comment: thanks. It is good question. I have installed maven and made clean install and all was ok. Seems that the problem only IntelliJ idea IDE.

Comment: I posted my comment as an answer since it solved your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try rebuilding the project. The code is valid and should compile. There must be a problem with the IDEA version you are using, somehow it gets in a state when it cannot correctly interpret the code.